# Access public method from another namespace in Unity

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, methods, namespaces

I am trying to access a public method from the `ARCoreBackgroundRenderer` class which is a MonoBehavior and is located in `GoogleARCore` namespace, in another class which is also MonoBehavior and named `UIController` and is located in another namespace called `CompanyController`. Is this possible? How can I do it?

the method I am trying to call in my second class is:

```
public void DisableARBackgroundRendering()
    {
        if (m_CommandBuffer == null || m_Camera == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        m_Camera.clearFlags = m_CameraClearFlags;

        .......

    }
```

I want to call this method in my second Class in a simple method.

Comment: What's wrong with just a "using ARCoreBackgroundRenderer;"?

Comment: @BernieG. `The type or namespace name 'ARCoreBackgroundRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` because its in another namespace.

Comment: Did you read my question? Put "using ARCoreBackgroundRenderer;" at the top of your code.

Comment: I did. but using that is producing that error. I wrote the error as well! I can not use that using. because it is in another namespace!

Comment: That's the point of a using statement... to import another namespace. Is the specified namespace/class included in your solution/project?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same project. but it is just not working. https://imgur.com/a/lGdkj6e

Comment: If arcorebackgroundrender is a class, you dont use the class as your using statement,  you use the name space its in..  try that.

Comment: @BugFinder Trying the namespace is also giving the same error. I think we can not use one namespace in another that simple. Plus there is a problem with monobehavior of the class which contains the method that has to be called.

Comment: Of course you can, we all do it all the time, thats what the using statements are for..  you cant just call a method, you would need the class, and so if x was the class in a namespace of mystuff, with a public method on the class of doit..  you might do using mystuff... then x myx=new x();, x.doit();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it helps to refer to the according [API](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity)

---

[`ARCoreBackgroundRenderer`](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/ARCoreBackgroundRenderer.cs) ([API Reference](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/class/GoogleARCore/ARCoreBackgroundRenderer)) as you said yourself is a **class** in the namespace `GoogleARCore` .. so import it via

```
using GoogleARCore;
```

or use

```
GoogleARCore.ARCoreBackgroundRenderer
```

as type in your code in `UIController`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleARCore;

namespace CompanyController
{
    public class UIController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Reference this via the Inspector by drag and drop 
        // [SerializeField] simply allows to serialize also private fields in Unity
        [SerializeField] private ARCoreBackgroundRenderer arRenderer;

        // Alternatively you could as said use the type like
        //[SerializeField] private GoogleARCore.ARCoreBackgroundRenderer arRenderer;

        private void Awake ()
        {
            // As a fallback find it on the scene
            if(!arRenderer) arRenderer = FindObjectOfType<ARCoreBackgroundRenderer>();
        }

        public void DisableARBackgroundRendering()
        {
            // Now use any public method of the arRenderer 
            arRenderer.SomePublicMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, you can also see that the method `DisableARBackgroundRendering` is `private` and you won't be able to use it. Also `m_Camera` and `m_CommandBuffer` are both `private` so you won't be able to access them.

What you **can** and - if you look closer into the implementation of `ARBackgroundRenderer` - **want** to do here is simply enabling and disabling the according component:

```
public void EnableARBackgroundRendering(bool enable)
{
    arRenderer.enabled = enable;
}
```

since internally it will take care of the rest itself and you don't need any further access to its methods, fields and properties:

> ```
> private void OnEnable()
> {
>     if (BackgroundMaterial == null)
>     {
>         Debug.LogError("ArCameraBackground:: No material assigned.");
>         return;
>     }
>
>     LifecycleManager.Instance.OnSessionSetEnabled += _OnSessionSetEnabled;
>
>     m_Camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
>
>     m_TransitionImageTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("ViewInARIcon");
>     BackgroundMaterial.SetTexture("_TransitionIconTex", m_TransitionImageTexture);
>
>     EnableARBackgroundRendering(); // AS YOU SEE IT ALREADY CALLS THIS ANYWAY
> }
>
> private void OnDisable()
> {
>     LifecycleManager.Instance.OnSessionSetEnabled -= _OnSessionSetEnabled;
>     m_TransitionState = BackgroundTransitionState.BlackScreen;
>     m_CurrentStateElapsed = 0.0f;
>
>     m_Camera.ResetProjectionMatrix();
>
>     DisableARBackgroundRendering(); // AS YOU SEE IT ALREADY CALLS THIS ANYWAY
> }
> ```

Comment: When I type using GoogleARCore it shows me that error. I can't call that namespace.

Comment: did you go through all steps of [Quickstart for Android](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android) or [Quickstart for iOS](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-ios)?

Comment: I did actually, but here I can not call `using GoogelARCore` to use that namespace. it tells me `The type or namespace name GoogleArCore could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Comment: It is not suggesting to me using that namespace.

Comment: No but it continues in the [Enable ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/enable-arcore) and finally reaches the [API](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity) which clearly says that the type is [`GoogleARCore.ARCoreBackgroundRenderer`](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unity/class/GoogleARCore/ARCoreBackgroundRenderer) which means you need this namespace. If it isn't recognized correctly something is wrong with the steps before. Check if everything is imported and in your buildsettings if you are on the correct target platform ...